# iOS reloading data from a webservice after an update

Tags: ios, json, web-services

I am writing an iOS application that loads data from a webservice and places the data in to a table view. A user can update the data in a cell by clicking the cell and then selecting a value. After that value is selected I want the table to update to reflect the new data, in essence re-do the initial download of data from the webservice. At the end of the update method, I call my initial load method, but this doesn't seem to work. It just reloads with all of the original data. Here is the end of my update method:

```
self.connectionInProgress = [[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self] autorelease];

[self loadLines];
```

And the load lines method:

```
- (void)loadLines
{   
    NSLog(@"going again?");
    [Results removeAllObjects];
    [Results release];
    Results = nil;
    Results = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{

        NSString *jsonString = [self performFetchWithURL:lineURL];
        if(jsonString == nil) {
            [self showNetworkError];
            return;
        }

        NSDictionary *dictionary = [self parseJSON:jsonString];
        if(dictionary == nil) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [self showNetworkError];
            });
            return;
        }

        [self parseDictionary:dictionary];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            isLoading = NO;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

The parseDictionary and performFetchWithURL are pretty standard JSON interaction in iOS 5... Putting the data in the Results array. Am I doing the right thing by clearing out my Results array and then recreating it?

How would I go about getting completely new data?

Comment: did you check the cache policy of your request?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly suggest looking into ASIHTTPRequest. It may or may not be the solution to your problem but it will remove alot of unnecessary code making your project easier to debug. 
GCD is great but when you spam it, it can get out of control very quickly and cause odd behaviors like you are experiencing.

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

```
//Unsafe_unretained is for ARC which it doesn't look like you are using.
__unsafe_unretained ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:lineURL]];

// Code inside of this block will run when the request finishes
// This code will also be called to on the main thread. So you can avoid your own GCD
[request setCompletionBlock:^{
    if (![request responseString])
    {
        [self showNetworkError];
        return;
    }
    NSDictionary *dictionary = [self parseJSON:[request responseString]];
    if(dictionary == nil) {
        [self showNetworkError];
        return;
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}];

//This code will run if your request fails
[request setFailedBlock:^{
     NSLog(@"Failed %@", [request error]);
}];

[request startAsynchronous];//Start the request
```

I would give it a shot. If this doesn't resolve your issue then it is very likely that your problems lays somewhere in code that you haven't posted.

I apologize for any syntax errors in that snippet I don't have a compiler handy.

Comment: I am pretty sure that ASIHTTP is no longer being maintained. I want to steer clear from third parties. Thanks for the help though!